# Git merge commits one by one

Tags: git, git-merge

Next to `master`, I have another remote repository `remote/master` from where I want to pull the changes then and again. This happens only about after every 20 commits or so. Consequently, it always generates these big behemoths of merge conflicts, where git wants me to resolve all 20 possible conflicts from 20 commits at once, without any further guidance.

Is there a way to be able to merge the branch, going through the commits one by one? So I can cross-check the individual conflicts with the commit messages and act accordingly. I understand that this could introduce unnecessary work when a commit undoes the changes from a previous one, but that is a very acceptable trade-off.

I know I can `git cherry-pick` them all, but how would I know since when to cherry-pick? Manually checking the log before every fake-"merge" process? Also, I'm not actually cherry-picking here. I want to combine two branches into one, but not all at once, as in

```
git pull --one-by-one remote master
```

Comment: You could merge each commit in one by one, not really much different to cherry picking but possible. You'd just have to replace the branch name with the commit hash

Comment: *Consequently, it always generates these big behemoths of merge conflicts*, well thats your actual issue, why are you getting so many conflicts. This all smells of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). My guess is your committing stuff into GIT you shouldn't be, assemblies or zip files of something.

Comment: I totally agree.  “Consequently, it always generates these big behemoths of merge conflicts” Solve that first. You’re doing something very wrong somewhere.

Comment: There *is* [git-imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge). It won't fix all problems, but it is sometimes useful for some merges.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. For context, the `remote/master` is an application template repository like [this one](https://github.com/agonxgashi/MEAN-template). The local repo applied heavy changes to it, but it is still worth tracking upstream changes for new features etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to be able to merge the branch, going through the commits one by one?

Not really, that's not how git does its thing. I guess you could merge each intermediate commit one by one, then take the resulting tree and create a synthetic "merge" commit.

> I know I can git cherry-pick them all, but how would I know since when to cherry-pick?

There's `git merge-base`, but I don't think that makes any sense. `remote/master` would usually be the "blessed" upstream, by cherrypicking its contents you're going to create completely unrelated commits in your branch (with similar content but not actually matching).

Most people would instead `rebase` their local changes onto the upstream.

> This happens only about after every 20 commits or so. Consequently, it always generates these big behemoths of merge conflicts

That sounds like some seriously weird development methodology.